# Encompassing object attributes with HTML and return in JSON

Tags: html, json, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

currently, i have written the following json search method.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(string videoTitle)
    {
        var auth = new Authentication() { Email = "abc@smu.abc", Password = "abc" };
        var videoList = server.Search(auth, videoTitle);
        String html = "";
        foreach(var item in videoList){
            var video = (Video)item;
            html += "<b>"+video.Title+"</b>";
        }

        return Json(html, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

On screen, it returns this.

```
"\u003cb\u003eAge of Conan\u003c/b\u003e"
```

what should i do? The reason why i want to do this is so that i can make use of CSS to style tags so that it looks aesthetically better as the items drop down from the search input.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return pure HTML you shouldn't return JSON, you should rather use the ContentResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult Search(string videoTitle)
{
    var auth = new Authentication() { Email = "smu@smu.com", Password = "test" };
    var videoList = server.Search(auth, videoTitle);
    String html = "";

    foreach(var item in videoList)
    {
        var video = (Video)item;
        html += "<b>"+video.Title+"</b>";
    }

    return Content(html, "text/html");
}
```

You can request that with standard jQuery.get() and insert directly into DOM.